# sticky Navbar main menu

Tags: css, menu, sticky

I have tried to make my main menu sticky, so that when I scroll through the website, the navbar is constantly at the top of the screen.

I have used:

```
nav.content{
    position:sticky;
    position:-webkit-sticky;
    top:0;
}
```

This code seems to work however My site is set out as so:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ....
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="logo"></div>
            <nav class="content">
               ......
            </nav>
        </header>
        <section class="site-content">
            .....
        </section>
        <footer>
            ....
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that the menu sticks until the header is out of sight and then the menu disappears so it does not come down onto the main content.

I was hoping someone could advise as to how to have the menu stick through a full scroll of the site

Answer (score 2):

Use fixed positioning

```
nav.content { 
     position:fixed;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     width:100%;
     z-index:100 }
```

You can make use of `Z-index` too, so that it stays on top of all your other content.

Answer (score 1):

Change CSS to:

```
nav.content{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Notice there's a " mistake in `class="site-content` line

Answer (score 0):

So, you are facing a problem to create a navbar, if the user scrolls the page navbar is not fixed to the top of the page, Right?

I will give you an example with the source code. Let's try the below code.

First, you have to understand what a sticky navbar is.
A sticky navbar is a popular design element used in websites for User interface. By keeping the navigation bar "sticky," or fixed to the top of the webpage, it remains visible as the user scrolls down, making it easier to navigate through the website.

Source Code : [Sticky Navbar](https://www.jsfeed.io/code/622tioe633/sticky-navigation-bar)

Example:
1] Use HTML

```
 <nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

2] Use Css

```
nav {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

3] Use JavaScript

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.querySelector("nav");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

This will help you to create a sticky navbar.